# Removing window decoration borders from a custom theme

Tags: unity, 15.10, themes

I have the Arc Darker theme on my Ubuntu 15.10. I quite like it, except for the fact that it has black window borders on the sides and the bottom (attached pic) which I don't fancy. I looked around the theme css files but could not find anything relevant. Any help appreciated.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: File `/usr/share/themes/Arc/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`  has almost 50 instances of `border-width`. Have you tried setting all of those to 0? Remember to backup the original file to facilitate recovery.